# IE8 CSS :not selector

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a website with an external CSS file that contains a :not selector;

```
ul.dynatree-container a:not(.remove){
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:3px;
    border:1px solid white
}
```

So  links within the .dynatree-container are styled, unless they have class="remove".

The contents of .dynatree-container is dynamic and loaded via AJAX.

This works fine, except in IE8 where the entire selector is ignored.

Is there a work-around/polyfilla?

I have tried Selectivizr but that requires the DOM elements don't change.

I am already using jQuery 1.9.1 so solutions based on that are valid.

Comment: If all else fails you could just add a new rule after this one specifying `!important` styles on `a.remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the need of using javascript, you may simply define those properties for all links

```
ul.dynatree-container a {
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:3px;
    border:1px solid white
}
```

and thus revert them with

```
ul.dynatree-container a.remove {
    ...
}
```

A bit verbose but it will work also on IE8

Comment: The only side effect I can see of this is that the link won't be styled using the browser default styles, however it does seem like the quick and easy work around.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Dean Edwards IE7.js, IE8.js and IE9.js, all of which can be [**found here**](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), specifically, IE9.js adds support for `:not`, from the Google Code page:

> **IE9.js** Upgrade(s) MSIE5.5-8 to be compatible with modern browsers.

[Direct link to js file](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js), and [example selectors by script](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html)

Comment: I've given that a go but have had a few problems to get it working with the dynamic DOM elements. 

I followed the thread [here](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=111#c12) and it sort of worked but other things on the Dynatree broke. It seems to be a lot of extra JavaScript for a one-off usage, so I will probably take the easy way out and add the extra CSS as per Frarizios suggestion.